# Почему не отправляются данные на сервер

Tags: kotlin, api, rest

Вкратце расскажу о проекте. Это приложение, где нужно обновлять и отправлять данные на сервер. С обновлением данных все хорошо, все работает, но с обновлением что-то не получается. Мне необходимо отправить конкретное значение (это PersonalityTypeInfo) на сервер. Токен у меня сохранен в sharedPreferences. Вот сам метод

```
private suspend fun sendPersonalityType() {
    val sharedPreferences = requireContext().getSharedPreferences("AuthData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val authToken = sharedPreferences.getString("token", null)
    val personalityTypeInfo = PersonalityTypeInfo(id = 18)

    if (!authToken.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            try {
                val response = userApi.sendPersonalityTypeInfo("Token $authToken", personalityTypeInfo)
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val personalityTypeInfo: PersonalityTypeInfo? = response.body()
                    if (personalityTypeInfo != null) {
                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                            updateUI()
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        showError("Ошибка получения данных пользователя")
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {

                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    showError("Ошибка при выполнении запроса")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В интерфейсе определила метод

```
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @PATCH("user_me")
    suspend fun sendPersonalityTypeInfo(@Header("Authorization") token: String,
                                        @Body userInfoRequest: PersonalityTypeInfo
): Response<PersonalityTypeInfo>
```

Где PersonalityTypeInfo, это data class PersonalityTypeInfo (val id: Int).
По дебагу я вижу, значение присваивается, токен тоже есть, но на этой строчке
val response = userApi.sendPersonalityTypeInfo("Token $authToken", personalityTypeInfo)
ничего не происходит. И ошибки тоже нет. Помогите разобраться

Comment: Не может ничего не происходить. Либо получаете `response`, либо попадаете в `catch` блок.

Comment: А нельзя посмотреть в логи retrofit'a? (судя по всему это он) - там же все будет видно